# Error when using the WHERE clause in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a datacontext that I'm trying to query, the results of which I want to bind to a gridview on a button click.  Getting connected to the datacontext works great.  I get the 1000s of records I expect. When I try to add the WHERE clause, I run into problems.  Here's the button event I'm trying to make it happen at:

```
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)         
      Dim dsource = New MY_DataContext().SV_XXXs '--- This works, the data is all there        
      gridRec.DataSource = dsource.ToList().Where(Function(dtable) dtable.PN = Session("PN"))   '--- this fails
      '--- Also tried this, it also did not work ----------------------------------------------------------
      '--- gridRec.DataSource = dsource.Where(Function(dtable) dtable.PN = Session("PN"))   '--- this fails
      '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      gridRec.DataBind()       
End Sub
```

The session variable is valid and the dsource is populating correctly, **but I get the following error when it tries to execute the Where clause**:

> Evaluation of method
>   System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1[SV_REC].get_Items() calls
>   into native method System.WeakReference.get_Target(). Evaluation of
>   native methods in this context is not supported.

Also tried:

```
Dim results =
        (
            From T In dsource
            Where T.PN = Session("SAFRReceiverPN")
            Select T
        ).ToList
```

And get this error

> Method 'System.Object CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object,
>   Boolean)' has no supported translation to SQL.

And tried:

```
Dim results = From t In dsource Where (t.PN = Session("SAFRReceiverPN")) Select t
```

nothing seems to work for me when trying a WHERE clause

C# or VB.NET are both cool if you have any suggestions.
Really, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Basically, fetch `Session("SAFERReceiverPN")` outside the query. Put it in a local variable. I'd expect that to be fine.

Comment: Thanks so much, that was it.  if you throw it up as an answer, i'll mark you for it.  already upvoted this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LINQ to SQL doesn't know what to do when you try to access the session inside the query. Instead of doing that, fetch the value from the session *before* the query and store the result in a local variable, then use that local variable in your query. For example, in C#:

```
var receiver = (string) Session["SAFRReceiverPN"];
var results = dsource.Where(t => t.PN == receiver);
```

(I don't bother with query expressions when you're just trying to perform a simple filter.)